# C# SslStream fails to authenticate when client cant validate the certificate

Tags: c#, http, https, sslstream

I am writing a very basic http/https server and have all the ground work laid out. it works just fine under normal circumstances. but if a users tries to connect using a different domain or ip that isn't on the certificate the sslstream throws an error and if i just catch the error and use the sslstream anyways any read or write method throws an error.

Is there anyway i can make the sslstream ignore the authentication error or implement a very basic ssl/tls system manually.

Comment: Give the `SslStream` constructor a `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback ` that always returns true

Comment: doesn't work, that callback is for when a client wants to connect to a server and wants to override the verification process. I just tested it.

Comment: Obviously the client is the one that needs to add the callback. You cannot force the client to ignore an authentication error

Comment: problem is im making a webserver that a web browser should be able to access so i cant modify the code of the client. i was hoping there was a way i could continue even with an invalid certificate because most browsers have a button to continue to the website even if the certificate isnt valid.

Comment: Perhaps set `SslServerAuthenticationOptions.ServerCertificate` to your self-signed cert, it may be trying to get a certificate that does not exist. Let's see your code

Comment: I'm not using asp.net I'm using .net framework so SslServerAuthentticationOption doesn't exist. Im not using a self signed certificate im using a valid certificate i got from lets encrypt. And it does find the certificate i have multiple checks in the code to find the certificate make sure its loaded and is a valid format and like i said in my post the server works just fine if you connect from the normal hostname it just fails to authenticate if the user uses a different hostname or uses the ip to connect.